# DDD-friendly ASP.NET MVC Model Binder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, modelbinders

I'm considering the value of a custom model binder that can instatiate immutable value objects defined in my domain layer. Then I can just pass them through the stack and set them on the appropriate entity. Has anyone tried? Had any luck? Think its a silly idea?

Comment: You don't define how and when you're going to use your immutable value objects and what do you mean by that. There're lots solutions to bind entities (by id from repository) - for example, in S#arp Architecture - but how are you going to bind value objects? By binding their fields? Can't default binder do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "value objects" you mean objects that can only be created by passing values to constructor, not by binding to fields, I think you have these solutions:

1. Write a custom binder - though I can't tell now how to access several fields at once in there.
2. Pass view model (that allows to bind to its fields) and then convert it to value object. Write a simple converter using reflection (couple of lines). You'll have to relate view model properties and constructor parameters either by name or by type. You can have your view model define what is the corresponding value type, and in action filter/OnActionExecuting call you converter - automatically. That's kind of semi-automatic model binding.
3. Pass something like FormCollection to action and then call your reflection method like var value = BindValue<ValueType>(formCollection).